# Strong markov property of Markov chain

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains, stopping-times

I have found an exercise in an old exam without a solution.

> Let $X_{0},X_{1},...$ be a Markov chain with state space $S$ and $N$ a stopping time. Let $\mathbb{E}_{x}(\cdot)$ denote the conditional expectation if I start in $x \in S$ and $\mathcal{A}_{N}$ the stopping time sigma algeba. Let $f$ be a non-negative function on $S^{k}$. If $\mathbb{P}(N < \infty) = 1$ then
>
> $$
> \mathbb{E}\left( f(X_{N},X_{N+1},...,X_{N+k-1}) | A_{N} \right) = \mathbb{E}_{X_{N}}\left( f(X_{0},X_{1},...,X_{k-1})\right)
> $$
>   for all $k \geq 1$.

Someone has an idea how to prove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $X_N$ is $\mathcal{A}_N$-measurable, the right-hand side of your equation is $\mathcal{A}_N$-measurable, and therefore the assertion follows if we can show that

$$\forall B \in \mathcal{A}_N: \quad \mathbb{E}(f(X_N,\ldots,X_{N+k-1}) 1_B) = \mathbb{E} \big[ 1_B \mathbb{E}_{X_N}(f(X_0,\ldots,X_{k-1})) \big]. \tag{1}$$

Fix $B \in \mathcal{A}_N$. As $N<\infty$ almost surely we have

$$\begin{align*} \mathbb{E}(f(X_N,\ldots,X_{N+k-1}) 1_B) &= \sum_{n =0}^{\infty} \mathbb{E}(f(X_N,\ldots,X_{N+k-1}) 1_B 1_{\{N=n\}}) \\  &= \sum_{n =0}^{\infty} \mathbb{E}(f(X_n,\ldots,X_{n+k-1}) 1_B 1_{\{N=n\}}). \end{align*} \tag{2}$$

Since $B \cap \{N=n\} \in \mathcal{F}_n$ it follows from the tower property that $$\begin{align*} \mathbb{E}(f(X_n,\ldots,X_{n+k-1}) 1_B 1_{\{N=n\}}) &= \mathbb{E} \big[ \mathbb{E}(f(X_n,\ldots,X_{n+k-1}) 1_B 1_{\{N=n\}} \mid \mathcal{F}_n) \big] \\ &= \mathbb{E} \big[ 1_B 1_{\{N=n\}} \mathbb{E}(f(X_n,\ldots,X_{n+k-1}) \mid \mathcal{F}_n) \big] \end{align*}$$

Using the Markov property of the Markov chain we get

$$\begin{align*} \mathbb{E}(f(X_n,\ldots,X_{n+k-1}) 1_B 1_{\{N=n\}}) &= \mathbb{E} \big[ 1_B 1_{\{N=n\}} \mathbb{E}_{X_n}(f(X_0,\ldots,X_{k-1})) \big] \\ &= \mathbb{E} \big[ 1_B \mathbb{E}(1_{\{N=n\}}\mathbb{E}_{X_N}(f(X_0,\ldots,X_{k-1})) \big]. \end{align*}$$

Plugging this into $(2)$ and using the monotone convergence theorem, we get $(1)$.

Comment: I'm really impressed of your skills. Very good job!

Comment: @love_math You are welcome.

Comment: one question: why is $\mathbb{E}(f(X_{n},...,X_{n+k-1}) | \mathcal{F}_{n}) = \mathbb{E}_{X_{n}}(f(X_{0},...,X_{k-1}))$. This definition of markov property i have never seen

Comment: @love_math There are several (equivalent) ways to state the Markov property and this is one of them. Which one(s) do you know?

Comment: I have the following definition: the process $(X_{n})$ on the state space $S$ posseses the markov property if for all $ n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $i_{0},...,i_{n-1},i,j \in S$ it holds that $\mathbb{P}(X_{n+1} = j | X_{n}=i,X_{n-1} = i_{n-1},...,X_{0} = i_{0}) = \mathbb{P}(X_{n+1} = j | X_{n} = i)$

Comment: @love_math I see... and you are sure that you are supposed to use definition to solve the exercise? Seems a pretty long exercise for an exam ...To get from your definition to the statement which I used you have essentially to use a monotone class argument... you might either ask this as a new question or hope that someone else will provide you with an alternative proof of the SMP.

Comment: I will ask as a new question